# Why does horizontal lines in plt.plot(feature, '.') mean that the data have been properly shuffled?

Tags: visualization, data-analysis

I am following a Mooc and [in this lecture about visualisation in explenatory data analysi](https://www.coursera.org/learn/competitive-data-science/lecture/zoIx3/visualizations)s the lecturer claims that when plotting the row indexes against feature values, if we have lines on the feature value axis it means that the data have been properly shuffled. I can't see why.

1. Shouldn't an index have only one value in the feature axis?
2. One horizontal line should mean that the feature values for all indexes have been uniformized, not randomized?

[image]

On the contrary, in the following lecture, the lecturer claims that from the absence of vertical lines, the data hasn't been properly shuffled:

[image]

I think I get it as if it was, I would have seen clear lines. But how can I bee sure there isn't more classes hidden in these subs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Shouldn't an index have only one value in the feature axis?

Yes, that's correct. On the graph given as example this is not visible because there are too many row indexes (50000). As a consequence it's impossible to distinguish a particular index from its neighbors, but if the X axis was stretched long enough one would see a single feature value for every index.

> 2. One horizontal line should mean that the feature values for all indexes have been uniformized, not randomized?

I think there could be two different confusions here:

- An horizontal line means that *a single feature value* is distributed uniformly across the indexes, which is equivalent to saying that *the indexes* are random for this feature value. In other words, the chance that this feature value appears at a particular index is the same as at any other index. This is what the author means: the order (indexes) is random for any feature value.
- The values for all the features have not been uniformized, this can be seen from the fact that vertically the density of the points is different around the middle (say 0.4-0.6) and the extremes (say 0-0.2 and 0.8-1). Of course this would be more visible with a standard histogram, which would show a kind of peak in the middle but with two high bars at the extremes for 0 and 1 (it can be seen from the continuous lines for these two features values that they appear much more frequently).

One may also note on this graph that there is some kind of underlying discrete distribution of the values: very clearly for values 0 and 1, but also from all the white horizontal lines which show that some values seldom exist in the data.

Comment: I think I understand, thanks. But why does these lines mean that the data has been properly shuffled?

Comment: "properly shuffled" means that order of the instances/points is random, i.e. the chance that a particular value appears at a particular index i is the same as for any other index j. The crucial point is that it's not about the distribution of the values (which stays the same before/after shuffling), it's about the distribution of the indexes given the values (as in my first point). The second graph you added shows a clear counter-example: given a particular value, its chances to be in different ranges of indexes are very different: for instance a value around 1.3 is very likely to fall ...

Comment: ... within indexes 2000-4000, and very unlikely to be anywhere else. In this cases the indexes are not random given a value.